# Prevent POST'ing from remote sites

Tags: forms, .htaccess, post, security

I'm just wondering how you go about preventing people trying to fool your script & POST'ing a similar looking form from a remote site.. say for example to try & put in extra values into select fields you don't have in yours or something of that nature.

Comment: You cannot prevent that from happening, even if you restrict posting data only from your server, people can use JS and plugins like firebug to modify the html of your page and submit modified data. Remember that you must never trust user input, and always validate everything server side. In fact if a person wants to submit their modified info, they will one way or another. Best protection is as said above tokens and referer checks, however referer can be spoofed, and token can be retrieved from your site before posting.

Comment: The only absolute solution would be based on IP .htaccess restriction, where you put the script to process the form completely separately, and then allow only the ip of your server to access that script. Even then, as said above, javascript etc can be used to modify the form, and you will need to validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), you should use a so called CSRF token that verifies the authenticity of the request. Additionally, you can check the HTTP *Referer* and only allow the transaction if it’s empty (not existing) or one of your addresses.

See also [OWASP’s Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea would be to create a md5 key generated from the user agent, ip and a time frame.  Then store that in a database and populate it in a hidden text field so on submit you can revalidate the value.

You can also use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get were the request came from and validate it against the url of your site.  Remember this is set by the user web browser so it can be spoofed.  Here is a list of available $_SERVER variables and their descriptions.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Just be aware that REFERER is easily forged.

Comment: Yeah I know about that but I avoid using it for that reason. It can be spoofed & also at times can be blank.

Comment: @Brett @Pete I added to my answer due to HTTP_REFERER issues.  Honestly I would never implement only the HTTP_REFEFER.  It's for additional security not basic security.